# Is an iframe considered an empty element even if it is showing an internal page within it?

Tags: html, css

Another week, another question I'm afraid. I've searched but I can't find an appropriate fix for this.  I have an svg image with a number of areas in and I want to show a new iframe, which I have wrapped in a div, on top of the existing content when the links in the svg image are clicked. The div will be the same each time but the content of the iframe will be sourced from a different internal page for each link clicked.
The link part of this seems to work as I have removed the 'display:none' from the '.ifallc:empty' and I can see the iframe in the div is being populated when I click the links.
The problem is that when I add '.ifallc:empty {display: none;}' the iframe disapears on page refresh but it does not come back when I click the link to populate the iframe.
My question is, is an iframe with content from another page loaded still considered empty?
And if it is is there a simple way around this?
There are going to be a lot of data in the links and I am trying to prevent all the data on the linked pages from loading before it needs to be.

I hope there is enough code here to see whats going on.

````
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.2rem;
    left: -.1rem;
    z-index: 2;
    /*background-color:#93c6e2;*/
    border: .15rem solid #222;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
    background: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    /* display: auto; */
    /* background: linear-gradient(rgb(85, 85, 85),rgb(255, 255, 255)); */
    /* display: none; /* FOR USE WHEN REQUIRED */
  }
        .ifallc { /*the iframe*/
            display: auto;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: auto;
            border: auto;
        }
        .ifallc:empty {
            display: none;
        }




<a href="peif.html" target="ifall">
  <path id="pe" class="landxx pe" d="m 649.707,798.409 c 0.997,-2.059 1.546,-3.468 3.113,-5.222 0.7,-0.783 1.24,-1.722 2.086,-2.366 0.613,-0.467 1.945,-1.093 2.001,-1.993 0.994,0.284 2.042,4.348 1.178,4.856 -0.629,0.37 -1.347,0.04 -1.8,0.682 -0.517,0.735 -0.401,1.737 0.622,1.882 -0.845,1.126 -0.609,2.552 0.724,1.115 1.17,-1.261 1.759,-0.377 2.87,0.565 0.952,0.808 2.042,-0.417 2.792,0.799 0.77,1.25 0.795,3.32 2.582,3.657 1.509,0.285 1.604,0.206 2.036,-1.463 2.884,-11.149 5.237,-15.065 1.92,-2.984 -0.482,1.754 0.515,-3.174 1.261,-4.859 0.383,-0.866 0.687,-1.349 0.701,-2.345 0,-0.632 0.957,-2.523 1.315,-0.825 0.241,-0.39 0.288,-0.8 0.141,-1.229 -0.06,-0.553 0.75,-1.151 1.045,-1.542 0.768,-1.021 1.729,-1.778 2.888,-2.309 2.522,-1.156 5.474,-1.581 7.776,-3.179 4.842,-3.362 8.195,-8.395 9.248,-14.131 0.394,0.417 0.873,0.583 1.439,0.5 -0.713,-1.66 0.03,-3.129 -0.958,-4.546 -0.39,-0.558 -2.329,-2.255 -2.209,-2.944 0.817,0.139 1.77,0.418 2.544,-0.04 0.767,-0.454 0.524,-0.602 1.389,-0.281 1.492,0.553 2.596,1.145 3.626,2.386 1.339,1.615 2.096,2.211 2.737,4.276 0.268,0.861 -0.07,1.565 1.122,1.668 1.151,0.1 0.85,0.56 1.646,1.271 1.544,1.381 2.681,0.646 3.219,3.003 0.417,1.826 0.339,2.265 2.286,2.848 2.098,0.628 0.117,3.076 1.188,4.296 0.581,0.661 1.487,0.886 2.335,0.851 0.529,-0.07 1.061,-0.118 1.595,-0.142 0.708,0 1.535,0.418 2.163,0.396 1.443,-0.05 3.152,-1.094 3.778,-2.353 0.661,-1.329 2.487,1.212 3.277,1.273 1.191,0.09 3.102,-1.774 3.95,-1.153 0.677,0.496 1.202,1.391 1.854,1.838 0.626,0.43 2.098,0.313 2.483,0.722 1.574,1.67 1.598,2.272 0.368,4.22 -0.985,1.56 -2.899,4.229 -3.172,6.044 -0.327,2.171 2.174,0.471 3.113,1.291 0.758,0.661 1.318,1.568 1.885,2.39 0.273,0.395 0.584,0.579 0.447,0.907 -0.09,0.7 -0.704,0.938 -1.131,0.151 -0.193,0.24 -0.386,0.48 -0.58,0.72 -1.122,-1.524 -3.609,-2.516 -5.024,-0.729 -1.613,2.038 -5.125,1.5 -7.443,2.114 -1.214,0.322 -1.801,1.67 -3.004,2.045 -1.264,0.395 -0.853,0.902 -1.695,1.66 -2.018,1.819 -3.416,1.297 -3.446,4.415 -0.01,1.081 0.06,1.987 -0.578,2.928 -0.603,0.895 -1.323,1.792 -1.083,2.939 0.249,1.19 1.275,2.882 -0.06,3.8 -1.119,0.771 -2.177,1.165 -3.094,2.24 -0.669,0.784 -1.017,1.675 -0.803,2.708 0.115,0.5 0.289,0.981 0.521,1.44 -0.559,0.243 -1.14,0.548 -1.561,1.001 -1.624,1.748 3.168,3.265 1.201,4.468 1.003,0.655 1.697,1.851 1.909,3.015 0.124,0.681 0.593,0.918 1.085,1.315 0.616,0.496 0.558,1.252 0.965,1.87 0.715,1.083 2.093,1.593 2.595,2.847 0.599,1.495 -0.55,2.408 -1.371,3.483 1.777,0.93 4.389,0.09 6.154,1.267 1.146,0.761 2.204,2.739 1.766,4.133 2.387,0.3 5.447,0.817 7.57,-0.636 1.34,-0.917 3.087,-4.232 4.891,-4.254 -0.211,0.867 -0.885,0.911 -0.355,1.807 0.562,0.951 -0.378,1.9 -0.318,2.986 0.154,2.824 0.251,5.72 0.593,8.527 0.927,-0.813 1.554,0.849 2.52,0.755 1.332,-0.13 2.266,-1.179 3.635,-1.167 1.306,0.01 2.252,-0.139 2.632,1.152 0.578,1.961 1.963,3.579 2.957,5.368 1.001,1.801 1.998,3.604 3.028,5.39 0.896,1.552 1.69,2.53 0.221,3.63 -1.295,0.969 -1.448,2.719 -0.977,4.115 0.408,1.205 0.109,2.815 0.177,4.988 0.03,0.937 1.17,2.128 1.211,3.1 0,0.06 -0.833,2.366 -0.9,2.427 -0.876,0.792 -1.396,2.227 -1.803,3.332 -0.744,2.019 1.247,2.191 1.252,3.76 0,1.114 -0.73,1.573 -0.938,2.653 -1.168,-0.801 -3.788,-3.527 -4.288,-1.497 -0.345,1.4 0.301,0.92 0.45,2.673 0.08,0.2 -1.168,-1.154 -0.666,-0.728 -0.01,0.296 -1.669,1.773 1.288,2.819 0.105,-1.402 1.81,0.859 2.605,0.633 0.456,-0.13 0.218,0.509 0.128,1.573 0.91,0.263 2.526,0.709 2.673,0.135 0.121,0.02 0.846,0.116 1.051,0.271 -0.585,3.217 -0.181,2.501 0.257,2.863 -0.323,0.668 0.139,0.516 -0.322,1.114 -0.792,1.028 -1.505,2.592 -2.458,3.539 -0.415,0.412 -0.99,0.631 -1.318,1.134 -0.602,0.923 0.647,0.492 0.808,1.265 0.207,0.991 0.606,0.956 0.253,1.399 -5.734,7.2 -1.924,0.984 -2.163,1.487 -0.536,1.129 0.861,2.579 0.105,3.875 -0.651,1.116 -2.026,1.511 -3.241,1.511 -1.364,0 -2.414,-1.019 -3.339,-1.891 -1.091,-1.027 -2.285,-1.508 -3.465,-2.344 -2.094,-1.483 -1.937,-4.181 -4.447,-5.211 -2.971,-1.22 -4.973,-4.122 -8.118,-4.896 -1.472,-0.362 -2.984,-1.379 -4.263,-2.175 -1.531,-0.952 -3.187,-1.271 -4.747,-2.112 -1.527,-0.825 -2.823,-2.085 -4.354,-2.957 -1.722,-0.98 -3.437,-1.941 -5.176,-2.894 -1.469,-0.805 -2.354,-2.651 -3.51,-3.84 -1.532,-1.576 -3.691,-2.404 -4.762,-4.36 -0.604,-1.104 -1.373,-2.43 -2.433,-3.095 -0.927,-0.582 0.304,-2.806 -1.32,-2.526 0.02,-0.281 0.09,-0.548 0.216,-0.8 0.242,0.144 0.482,0.291 0.72,0.44 0.64,-3.198 -0.743,-4.856 -2.346,-7.476 -1.456,-2.38 -2.445,-4.897 -4.486,-6.832 -0.612,-0.581 -1.237,-0.887 -1.07,-1.682 0.192,-0.915 -0.344,-1.942 -0.781,-2.704 -0.429,-0.749 -0.948,-1.552 -1.613,-2.117 -0.612,-0.521 -1.657,-0.768 -2.046,-1.526 -0.05,-0.397 -0.01,-0.791 0.107,-1.18 -0.121,-0.863 -0.668,-1.851 -1.061,-2.615 -0.753,-1.465 -1.781,-2.763 -2.616,-4.179 -0.787,-1.334 -1.229,-2.932 -1.786,-4.369 -1.3,-3.356 -3.396,-5.94 -4.338,-9.185 -1.287,-4.429 -5.048,-7.125 -6.755,-11.5 -1.953,-5.004 -5.991,-8.57 -10.887,-10.634 -0.431,-0.182 -2.046,-0.57 -2.101,-1.167 -0.08,-0.832 -0.251,-2.22 0.944,-2.072 2.126,0.264 1.319,-1.746 0.631,-2.793 -0.971,-1.477 -1.937,-2.094 -1.988,-3.931 0.197,-0.236 0.389,-0.476 0.576,-0.72 -0.04,-0.28 -0.885,-1.054 -1.074,-1.268 -0.994,-1.12 -0.386,-1.78 -0.802,-3.047">
    <title>First</title>
  </path>
</a>
<div class="miscbar"><iframe name="ifall" class="ifallc"></iframe></div>```
````

Answer (score 1):

As per the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty), the `:empty` pseudo-class matches elements that has **no children**. By children, it means it could either be an element or just text.

If you defined your `iframe` like this:

```
<iframe src="//example.com"></iframe>
```

It will be counted as empty. (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wz0fv1md/1/))

However, if you start adding texts inside:

```
<iframe src="//example.com">No iframe support</iframe>
```

It will not be considered empty. (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wz0fv1md/))

Comment: I did see this but I thought the contents of the page loading into the iframe would then give that iframe children (the contents of the included html document being the children), but clearly that's not how it works. I don't think this is going to work with :empty so Ill go back to the drawing board and find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it :) I put an empty header in the wrapper div (misc bar) which contains the iframe and removed the line height and visibility of the header. Then I sent some text to that header at the same time the iframe is populated. I can now add border and background to the contents of the html which will only appear when the link is clicked.

```
<a href="peif.html" target="ifall" onclick="document.getElementById('miscbartitle').innerHTML = 'Enjoy'">


  .miscbar { /*the outer div*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.2rem;
    left: -.1rem;
    z-index: 2;
    /*
    border: .15rem solid #222;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
    background: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
  }
        .ifallc { /*the iframe*/
            display: auto;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: auto;
            border: auto;
            border: none;
        }       
        #miscbartitle {
            visibility: hidden;
            line-height: 0;
        }
```